# Is there a clever way to do this with pure math

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I've got this spot of code that seems it could be done cleaner with pure math (perhaps a logarigthms?). Can you help me out?

The code finds the first power of 2 greater than a given input. For example, if you give it 500, it returns 9, because 2^9 = 512 > 500. 2^8 = 256, would be too small because it's less than 500.

```
function getFactor($iMaxElementsPerDir)
{
    $aFactors = range(128, 1);
    foreach($aFactors as $i => $iFactor)
        if($iMaxElementsPerDir > pow(2, $iFactor) - 1)
            break;
    if($i == 0)
        return false;
    return $aFactors[$i - 1];
}
```

The following holds true

```
getFactor(500)  = 9
getFactor(1000) = 10
getFactor(2500) = 12
getFactor(5000) = 13
```

Comment: you could remove the code and ask about an algorithm on: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dagon I don't believe a math algorithm is actually required for this :)

Comment: i don't know, i consider counting  past 10  higher mathematics

Comment: @Dagon Thought about math.stackexchange.com and even started writing a post there, but decided to try here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as jack but shorter. Log with base 2 is the reverse function of 2^x.

```
echo ceil(log(500, 2));
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted, but it seems good to me. I've upvoted for it myself.

Comment: @quickshiftin: Because it's broken.  It *almost* works, and that's the really insidious kind of not working.

Comment: @tmyklebu What's an input that this or Jack's answer fails for? I'm just curious to understand better.

Comment: @tmyklebu yes it will fail with really big numbers because PHP will convert it to float internally. (> 32 or 64 bit) But I fear the bit operations will also totally fail.

Comment: When we say "really big numbers", how big are we talking about? In reality I don't expect very big number as input. Maybe like 250k, 500k..? It's supposed to represent how many objects you'd like to store in a directory. Practically, I'd expect the values to be sane...

Comment: I'm not going to lie, this is my favorite of the solutions. Simple, to the point and should work within the practical limits of my use cases.

Comment: @quickshiftin: Try 536870912 and 536870913.

Comment: @bitWorking: No, that's not even why it fails.  It fails long before that matters.  It fails because `log(x) / log(2)` isn't rounded in the exact way that's necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the same effect by shifting the bits in the input to the right and checking against 0. Something like this.

```
i = 1
while((input >> i) != 0)
    i++

return i
```

Comment: This is the right general approach. Google "bit twiddling hacks" for faster (in general) but less comprehensible tricks....

Comment: And now everyone else knows, I pretty much slept through the bit shifting segment of computer science! Nice catch @Beed, I like this solution.

Comment: Except bit shifting to get a result is a "pure math" expression like the other answers

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a "math only" solution (that is a single expression or formula), you can use [`log()`](http://php.net/log) and then take the ceiling value of its result:

```
$factors = ceil(log(500) / log(2)); // 9
$factors = ceil(log(5000) / log(2)); // 13
```

I seem to have not noticed that this function accepts a second argument (since PHP 4.3) with which you can specify the base; though [internally](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/math.c#678) the same operation is performed, it does indeed make the code shorter:

```
$factors = ceil(log(500, 2)); // 9
```

To factor in some inaccuracies, you may need some tweaking:

```
$factors = floor(log($nr - 1, 2)) + 1;
```

Comment: Careful with that.  `log(foo) / log(2)` might not be exact even when `foo` is a power of two.

Comment: It's only accurate in theory if your theory doesn't account for how anything works.

Comment: Why not just use `log(foo, 2)`?

Comment: @openorclose Yes, that would work too. I didn't know `log()` had another argument, but internally it performs the same operation anyway.

Comment: @Jack internally and mathematically aren't the same thing.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Not sure what you mean by that; internally it does `log(n) / log(b)` when you pass the second argument.

Comment: @Jack not sure what I meant by that either.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Zero all but the most significant bit of the number, maybe like this:

   `while (x & x-1) x &= x-1;`

   and look the answer up in a table.  Use a table of length 67 and mod your power of two by 67.
2. Binary search for the high bit.
3. If you're working with a floating-point number, inspect the exponent field.  This field contains 1023 plus your answer, except in the case where the number is a perfect power of two.  You can detect the perfect power case by checking whether the significand field is exactly zero.
4. If you aren't working with a floating-point number, convert it to floating-point and look at the exponent like in 3.  Check for a power of two by testing `(x & x-1) == 0` instead of looking at the significand; this is true exactly when `x` is a power of two.

Note that `log(2^100)` is the same `double` as `log(nextafter(2^100, 1.0/0.0))`, so any solution based on floating-point natural logarithms will fail.

Here's (nonconformant C++, not PHP) code for 4:

```
int ceillog2(unsigned long long x) {
  if (x < 2) return x-1;
  double d = x-1;
  int ans = (long long &)d >> 52;
  return ans - 1022;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your note after point 4, is a bit shifting solution like @Beed's answer ideal? Also, fwiw, I expect to take integers as input.

Comment: @quickshiftin: Convert Beed's to do a binary search instead of a linear search and it's pretty good.  I'd use the `ceillog2` I posted here, but I have no idea how to convert it to PHP.

Comment: How does that `ceillog2` work anyway? What does `(long long &)d` mean?

Comment: @Jack: Convert to `double`.  Then pull out the exponent.  `(long long &)d` lets me interpret `d` bitwise as a 64-bit integer.  `>> 52` shifts out the significand, leaving only the (biased) exponent and the (zero) sign bit.  Then I just subtract off the right number, which happens to be 1022.  (This is technically illegal C++, but making it legal results in a bit of ugliness.)

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how doubles are laid out in memory?

Comment: @Jack: It depends on the floating-point format being IEEE-754's binary64 format and floating-point numbers and 64-bit integers having the same endian.